# Admob test ads not showing but real ads are

Tags: android, admob

Right now there are no test ads showing up on my devices.

I have called adTestDevice for each of my devices and made sure they are correct ID's.

It is funny because when I remove the test device code I get real ads, but when I use addTestDevice, no ads show up. I can see the ad requests being called in my logcat but no test ads showing.

Did anyone else ever encounter this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes TestAds are broken, it happened few times to me. Try a different time it might start working again.

Comment: Yeah, this happends quite often.  Happened to me a few times, too.  Can take more than one day to recover.